# Cannot find an overload for 'contains' that accepts an argument list of type '([Int], Expression<String>)'

Tags: sqlite, swift, sqlite.swift

I use [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift)

I tried the expression:

```
userTable.filter(contains([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], entryId))
```

from the example. But I got the following error:

```
Cannot find an overload for 'contains' that accepts an argument list of type '([Int], Expression<String>)'
```

**How can I make this work?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite.swift, like Swift itself, is type-safe, so the column expression you filter must be the same type as the array you're checking.

It appears that `entryId` is of type `Expression<String>`, which would be similar to writing the following vanilla Swift:

```
contains([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "1")
```

This actually fails with a very similar error message.

> Cannot find an overload for 'contains' that accepts an argument list of type '([Int], String)'

If you expect `entryId` to be an `Int`, then it should be defined as such:

```
let entryId = Expression<Int>("entryId")
```

With this change in place, `contains` should work just fine.